# Sending headers with websocket connection request (Mojolicious)

Tags: perl, websocket, mojolicious

I need to open a websocket connection from Perl with a server. I got it working on echo.websocket.org, but when I replace the websocket.org with the real server, the handshake fails. I suspect I need to send some extra headers but I'm unsure how to do that. I'm using Mojolicious to make the connection:

```perl
use strict;

use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Mojo::IOLoop;

# Open WebSocket
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
$ua->websocket('wss://someserver.com/' => {
'Origin' => 'https://www.myserver.com',
'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions' => 'permessage-deflate'
} => sub {
  my ($ua, $tx) = @_;

  # Check if WebSocket handshake was successful
  unless( $tx->is_websocket ) {
    print "Handshake failed!\n";
    return;
  }

  # Wait for WebSocket to be closed
  $tx->on(finish => sub {
    my ($tx, $code, $reason) = @_;
    print "WebSocket closed with status $code.\n";
  });

  # Close WebSocket after receiving one message
  $tx->on(message => sub {
    my ($tx, $msg) = @_;
    print "WebSocket message: $msg\n";
    $tx->finish;
  });

  # Send a message to the server
  $tx->send("Hello world!");
});

# Start event loop if necessary
Mojo::IOLoop->start unless Mojo::IOLoop->is_running;

print "Done.\n";
```

As you can see, I'm trying to add two request headers: **Origin** and **Sec-WebSocket-Extensions**.

Is this the proper way to do it? I'm asking because the handshake still fails.

Comment: You essentially ask how to solve a problem which happens with one server but not with another server - without providing any usable information about the other server and how exactly it fails. This makes it impossible to understand why the problem happens and to help you. Instead you seem to randomly fiddle with some additional headers for no apparent reason. And, you cannot just add some arbitrary `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions` header without actually supporting the given extensions.

Comment: Well, the question is: "how do I add extra headers to a websocket connection request". The question isn't "what's the problem here". Like I said, I suspect the lack of certain headers is the problem here but I can't be sure since I can't find in the Majolicious documentation how to send multiple header. So that's my first question: "Is this the way to send extra headers?"

Comment: If you only want to know if this is the correct way to add headers: yes it is and it is [also documented as such](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent#toc). Why it still fails: no idea since it is not clear what your server expects and how exactly your code fails. It might for example fail already during the SSL handshake which is before it even sends any HTTP headers.

Comment: I know the documentation states how to set the 'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions' header. But it doesn't mention you can set arbitrary headers the same way. And if you can, I was wondering if what I did is the proper way to send **multiple** headers.

Comment: The documentation has even an example where it sets the `DNT` header. And yes, you can set multiple headers this way at once (just tried it) and you also did it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

One proper way might be to set the headers each time you perform a http request, which should also include web socket type of requests ... and in a way which is specified by the web socket server side ...

```
my $ua  = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
$ua->on(start => sub {
   my ($ua, $tx) = @_;
   $tx->req->headers->header('Sec-WebSocket-Extensions' => 'foo-bar-extensions');
   $tx->req->headers->header('Origin' => 'foo-bar-origin'); 
});

$ua->websocket('ws://my.server/jsonecho' => sub {
   my ($ua, $tx) = @_;
   say 'WebSocket handshake failed!' and return unless $tx->is_websocket;
   $tx->on(json => sub {
   my ($tx, $hash) = @_;
   say "WebSocket message via JSON: $hash->{msg}";
   $tx->finish;
   });
   $tx->send({json => {msg => 'Hello World!'}});
 });
```